# Flutter widget slowly changing view on picture

Tags: flutter, dart, package

I am looking for a flutter package or widget, that enables a slow change of the spot seen in the picture so that a natural and modern look gets created.
If you got an easy idea about how to create something like this please also share.
It should look more or less like here:
https://normcph.com/
Thanks for every reply!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [kenBurnsView](https://pub.dev/packages/kenburns) or [parallax_bg](https://pub.dev/packages/parallax_bg). Just use the package and modify the the configuration based on your need.

I will recommend you to use [kenBurnsView](https://pub.dev/packages/kenburns) because it is very simillar to native android [kenBurnsView-Android](https://github.com/flavioarfaria/KenBurnsView)

Comment: Thanks! It's close enough